# node.js get new data without refresh

Tags: node.js

I am writing an app where server will automatically send new data as soon as content of the file changes, and browser is supposed to display it. However, i need to use "refresh" every time to find out what the new data is. here is client code:

```
<script>
var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.91:8070');
socket.on('news', function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                document.forms['test form'].elements["txtStatus"].value = data;
});
</script>
```

and here is the server code:

```
var http = require('http');
var io = require('/home/pi/node/lib/node_modules/socket.io');
var server;
var fs = require('fs');

server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write('My first node app.');
  res.end();
}),

server.listen(8070);

var io = io.listen(server);

var prev_text;
var text =  fs.readFileSync('./current_temp','utf8');

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

socket.emit('news', text);
fs.watchFile('./current_temp', function (curr, prev) {
text = fs.readFileSync('./current_temp','utf8');
       if(prev_text != text){
                prev_text = text;
                socket.emit('news', text);
                console.log("text is :"+text);
        }
});


} );
```

it's weired because sometimes it works but most of the times it does not when i am testing it. I have no idea what makes it work. Also I intended that watchFile kindda puts this program in a loop, from which I can make emits as soon as the content of the file changes.

Also any other comments are welcome about this code. I am new to sockets.io and node.js, and therefore may not be doing something right ... Thank you in advance for the answer.

The question is again, how can I make it in such a way that browser updates data without refresh on the client side.

Comment: One general comment is that you should avoid as much of the *Sync functions as you can, especially readFileSync. Node.js is non blocking, and the way you're using it is you're blocking the whole server (single-threaded, remember?) until that file is read. Not really awesome for performance.

Comment: Also I think your problem might be that you'd want to pull out the socket variable, so that it's acessible from both watchFile callback and from socket.on('connection') callback. And also, I'd take a look at patterns of when does this work. If you try to save the file change before you make your first connection, does the refresh work? Or only once after your first connection to socket.io?

Comment: You are right about saving changes, it works in one of the cases, but i can't figure out when, i just saw it couple of times. As far as pulling socket out of socket.on, i tryed, but it did not work eather. here is what I tryed: var global_sock;
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
 global_sock = socket;
});
global_sock.emit ...

but it did not work eather for some reason. perhaps you could tell me how to pull it put out ?

Comment: As i removed the if statement it started updating browser in real time. still i would like to know how to make it better

Comment: still i would like to get that socket out of sockets.on.connection

Answer (score 2):

Your approach isn't good, but that's not a problem as you said you're new to socket.io. You need to refresh the page because you're not using `socket.io`'s default events in a meaningful manner. When you refresh the page, a new connection is made between client and server and you're firing your 'news' event in there. Do it like this:

```
var prev_text;
var text =  fs.readFileSync('./current_temp','utf8');
fs.watchFile('./current_temp', function (curr, prev) {
text = fs.readFileSync('./current_temp','utf8');
   if(prev_text != text){
            prev_text = text;
            io.sockets.emit('news', text);
            console.log("text is :"+text);
    }
});
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', text);
});
```

io.sockets.emit is a default event which emits data to all connected clients and you can use it out of the scope of `io.sockets.on('connection')`

I think you can detect a file change with [chokidar.js](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar).
Each time your file changes, an event will be triggered and there you can fire your 'news' event.
Also you can detect it with this:

```
fs.watch("c:\\sim", { persistent: true }, function (event, fileName) {
console.log("Event: " + event);
io.sockets.emit('news', text);
});
```

Hope this works!

Comment: Actually in the old code after I removed conditional "if" statement, it started working. I think I tryed your version but it did not work, i will try it again tomorrow though. With your approach how am i triggering the sockets.on event to fire emmit as soon as the file is updated ? I don't see it in the code ...

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't notice that, i've edited my answer